# My redis stop working and fail to restart

Tags: docker, redis

I started a redis via docker on my server (managed with traefik)
But my Redis always finish to fail, I don't understand why.
And the only method I found to restart is to delete /data/dump.rdb and restart my redis.

```
 * Connecting to MASTER 19XXXXXXXXX
 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
 * Full resync from master: ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ:1
 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving 54992 bytes from master to disk
 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Flushing old data
 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Loading DB in memory
 # Wrong signature trying to load DB from file
 # Failed trying to load the MASTER synchronization DB from disk: Invalid argument
 * Reconnecting to MASTER 19XXXXXXXXX after failure
 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
 * Connecting to MASTER 19XXXXXXXXX
 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
```

Redis Docker Compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:7.0"
    container_name: "redis"
    command: "redis-server"
    networks:
      - "traefik"
    restart: "always"
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - "/root/redis/data:/data"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample `docker-compose.yml` file for running a `Redis` server using `Docker Compose`

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Above yml uses the official redis image from Docker Hub and exposes the service on port 6379 and maps it to the host machine's port 6379.

It's a minimal example. Hope it helps.